# VMWare workstation installation error: The MSI '' failed

Tags: windows-7, installation, vmware-workstation

I am installing on windows 7. The vmware workstation version is 9.0.2-1031769.

Installation proceeds as expected until about 70% when it fails with the following error:

```
The MSI '' failed.
```

I have followed every single step on this [supposed fix](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1031302) except that I was not able to delete a coupled of files in the temp directory but I do not think they are related to vmware. And it still didn't work.

Next I deleted every single reference to vmware in the registry also to no avail.

Comment: look into the temp folder for a setup log file and upload this file please.

Comment: @magicandre1981 here it is: http://pastebin.com/F1pQjBmJ

Comment: how much RAM and free HDD space do you have? You get this error: VNLCallBridgeIoctl: ioctl call failed: 0x000005aa. And **0x000005aa** means **ERROR_NO_SYSTEM_RESOURCES** so not enough resources.

Comment: @magicandre1981 i have 8gig ram and 200gb free hard drive space

Comment: hm, this is wired. Ask in the vmware forums: http://communities.vmware.com/community/vmtn/workstation/content?filterID=contentstatus[published]~objecttype~objecttype[thread]

Answer (score -3):

Steps to solve this problem:

- Start Menu ->My Computer ->right click ->Properties ->Advance system setting ->Advance -> Environment variable
- now in top user you can find temp and tmp in user variables
- now click on edit and save its variable value on notepad.Do it for both temp
- create a folder in c: drive as tmp. Now copy the location c:/tmp
- Replace variable value to c:/tmp for both Temp and Tmp
- now click on ok and restart your system.

Now try to install VMWare and it will 100% working for me. Don't forget to replace the variable value of Temp and Tmp to url which you save on notepad.

Comment: I understand that you are suggesting to change environment variables but I cannot see how this is relevant here. Also this answer needs some grammar and formatting improvements