# Repairing Windows Installer on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, installation, 64-bit, vmware-workstation, windows-installer

I have the [VMWare MSI '' failed](https://superuser.com/questions/594174/vmware-workstation-installation-error-the-msi-failed) issue. Unfortunately this question does not have an answer yet.

I'm stuck at step 4 of the official [VMWare troubleshouting website regarding this issue](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1031302)

Basically it says

`Run the installer of the currently installed version of Windows installer [original text "Workstation" seems to be wrong] and choose Repair`

However, when I follow the link, it only brings me to Windows Installer Redistributables for Version 4.5. Windows 7 needs Windows Installer 5.0. Microsoft says:

> There is no redistributable for Windows Installer 5.0

I have also tried

> Start Windows Installer Service
>   Run MSIExec /UNREGISTER
>   Run MSIExec /REGSERVER
>   regsvr32.exe /s %windir%\system32\msi.dll

**How can I repair Windows Installer 5.0?**

> Versions:
>   Windows 7 SP1 x 64
>   old VMWare Workstation 8.0.6
>   trying to install new VMWare Workstation 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Microsoft Fixit Utility KB2438651](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2438651) did the job.